# Formatting disinct columns with Variable but equal number of rows, and the columns are not adjacent

Tags: vba, excel, excel-automation

My data have 10+ columns and from that i want to select three columns and **further format those three columns**, but the no. of rows are not fixed so I'm unable to select all those three columns at once.
Here is what I'm trying to do

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("G2:H" & lastrow, "J2:J" & lastrow).Select
```

But this is selecting I columns as well.
I tried this also

```
Range("G2:H & lastrow, J2:J" &lastrow).select
```

But this gave me error as expected.

When using

```
Range("J2:J" & lastrow).Select 
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

The data gets formatted properly but I want to do this for all three columns which are not adjacnet
[image: Screenshot 1]

But if I use

```
 Intersect(Range("G:H, J:J"), Rows("2:" & lastrow)).Select
 With Selection
     .NumberFormat = "0"
     .Value = .Value
 End With
```

Columns G and H gets formatted properly but Columns J is not, it gives me #NA entries.
[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to loop through each contiguous range, which you can get by means of `Areas()` property, as follows:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim area As Range

With Intersect(Range("G:H, J:J"), Rows("2:" & lastrow))
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    For Each area In .Areas
        area.Value = area.Value
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Can you give me a link/source from where I can learn advance topics in VBA-excel, I know basic coding whatever I learnt from macro recorder and some sites.